# Kentico - Display content of localization resource strings through repeater transformation

Tags: kentico

I have a custom pagetype with 1 text field where I keep re-usable html content to be included on other pages through a repeater. The transformation for the repeater has just 1 line of code *`<%# Eval("Content") %>`*.

I'm running into a situation where I want to use a resource string inside the content box together with other html content, something like `{$ site.languages $}`. However, when viewing, the pages displays this string `{$ site.languages $}` instead of the value of the resource string. Is it possible to display the resource string content in this case and how?

Comment: you are also mixing ASCX code <%# ... %> with macro {$ ... $} which won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<%# Localize(Eval("Content")) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. ASCX transformations – call the Localize transformation method:

   **<%# Localize("Text containing localization expressions: {$stringKey$}") %>**
2. Text / XML transformations – use localization string macro expressions or the 
   GetResourceString macro method:

   **{$stringKey$} - OR - {% GetResourceString("stringKey") %}**